# how to get xml data from a sp that has for xml using sql helper

Tags: c#, xml, t-sql

We are trying to get data to a file , which is prepared using "select...for XML"
The code fragment that we are trying is :

```
filename = "";
filename = txtFolderPath.Text + roww[0].ToString() + ".xml";
SqlParameter[] a = new SqlParameter[1];
a[0] = new SqlParameter("@p_document_no", DbType.String);
a[0].Value = roww[0].ToString();
dtxml = SqlHelper.ExecuteXmlReader(Properties.Settings.Default.ConStr, 
      CommandType.StoredProcedure, "dbo.PR_GENERATE_INVOICE_XML", a);
```

the error we get :

> Error 3   The best overloaded method match for
>   'SqlHelper.ExecuteXmlReader(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection,
>   System.Data.CommandType, string, params
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[])' has some invalid arguments

In the stored procedure, some values are calculated before entering the select portion of the sp so running as sql text command will not produce the desired output.

Any ideas are welcomed

Comment: any examples are also welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing in a SqlConnection which is what the method wants, you're passing a connection string. Use that to create the connection.

try...

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConStr);
dtxml = SqlHelper.ExecuteXmlReader(conn, 
      CommandType.StoredProcedure, "dbo.PR_GENERATE_INVOICE_XML", a);
```